# Poco::Net HTTPServer: How to detect disconnected clients?

Tags: c++, http, poco-libraries

I'm working on an http server as part of my C++ application, based on Poco::Net HTTP. It's pretty straight-forward, using `Poco::Net::HTTPServer`, then a `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler` subclass, implementing `void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest &req, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse &resp)`. In this method, processes can become time-consuming, and may even run endless in some situations.

Browsers use those server from inside a web application, by ajax requests (`XMLHttpRequest`), and sometimes `abort()` those requests (which closes the connection?!).

How can I detect this situation inside `handleRequest(...)` in order to stop processing?

btw: I literally need this flow of things. Recommendations regarding different, maybe asynchronous ways e.g. of passing the data will not work. If Poco can't do that, I have to replace it.

Neither the documentation nor some experiments with `Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest` and `Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse` helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I have also had this issue and asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75185587/12664906) more specific question on StackOverflow about detecting disconnection for an image streamer. After working on this problem for a while, I figured out a solution.

### TLDR

The key for being able to detect disconnections is to have access to the `StreamSocket` created by the `HTTPServer`. By having this, you can create a `HTTPServerSession`, and use the `session.socket().sendBytes()` function in a loop to send information to the client. This function is useful, because when the client disconnects, it throws an `I/O Error`, which can be handled in a try catch block, and break out from any loop that keeps sending the information. Also, in the Poco `HTTPRequestHandler` the `HTTPServerResponse` and the `HTTPServerRequest` is also created from this `HTTPServerSession` behind the scenes, but somewhy the session was not provided in the `HTTPRequestHandler`'s `handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response)` function, which I believe is a heavy defect.

So to come around this issue, I used some of the Poco::Net classes as base classes and made my own `ICustomHTTPRequestHandler` interface, which had the function `void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession& session, Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) = 0` abstract function, containing the `session` variable.

With this, detecting the disconnected clients looks like:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        std::string someString = "someString";
        session.socket().sendBytes(someString.c_str(), static_cast<int>(someString.length()));
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

### Long version with implementation

So to start with, we have the **main.cpp**, which contains a Poco `ServerApplication` as an example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerParams.h"
#include "Poco/Util/Application.h"
#include "Poco/Util/HelpFormatter.h"
#include "Poco/Util/Option.h"
#include "Poco/Util/OptionSet.h"
#include "Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h"

#include "CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp"
#include "CustomHTTPServer.hpp"

class App final : public Poco::Util::ServerApplication {
 private:
    bool helpRequested{false};

    void initialize(Application& self) override {
        loadConfiguration();
        ServerApplication::initialize(self);
    }

    int main(const std::vector<std::string>& args) override {
        if (helpRequested) {
            return Application::EXIT_OK;
        }

        Poco::UInt16 port = static_cast<Poco::UInt16>(config().getInt("HTTPServer.port"));
        CustomHTTPServer httpServer(new CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory{},
                                   port,
                                   new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams{});
        httpServer.start();

        waitForTerminationRequest();
        httpServer.stop();

        return Poco::Util::Application::EXIT_OK;
    }

    void defineOptions(Poco::Util::OptionSet& options) override {
        Poco::Util::ServerApplication::defineOptions(options);

        options.addOption(
            Poco::Util::Option("help", "h", "Display argument help information.")
                .required(false)
                .repeatable(false)
                .callback(Poco::Util::OptionCallback<App>(this, &App::handleHelp)));
    }

    void handleHelp(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) {
        std::ignore = name;
        std::ignore = value;
        Poco::Util::HelpFormatter helpFormatter(options());
        helpFormatter.format(std::cout);
        stopOptionsProcessing();
        helpRequested = true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    App app;
    return app.run(argc, argv);
}
```

In this, we create a `CustomHTTPServer`, and give it a `CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory::Ptr`, just like when creating a `Poco::Net::HTTPServer`. The `CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory` object is customized by the user and derived from the `ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory` interface. I will show an example for the `CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory` class later, but first lets see the interface class. This will handle the incoming HTTP/TCP connections and call the specific requestHandlers based on the requested path.

**ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandlerFactory.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerSession.h"

#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"

class ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory {
 public:
    using Ptr = Poco::SharedPtr<ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory>;
    ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory() = default;
    virtual ~ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory() = default;
    virtual ICustomHTTPRequestHandler::Ptr createRequestHandler(const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request) = 0;
};
```

This should return a `ICustomHTTPRequestHandler::Ptr`, when `createRequestHandler(const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request)` function is called.

**ICustomHTTPRequestHandler.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerSession.h"
#include "Poco/SharedPtr.h"

class ICustomHTTPRequestHandler {
 public:
    using Ptr = Poco::SharedPtr<ICustomHTTPRequestHandler>;
    ICustomHTTPRequestHandler() = default;
    virtual ~ICustomHTTPRequestHandler() = default;
    virtual void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession& session,
                               Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request,
                               Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) = 0;
};
```

This class contains the new `handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession& session, ...)` function, which will make it possible to detect disconnected clients through the **session parameter**.

**CustomHTTPServer.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerParams.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/TCPServer.h"
#include "Poco/ThreadPool.h"

#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp"
#include "CustomHTTPServerConnectionFactory.hpp"

class CustomHTTPServer : public Poco::Net::TCPServer {
 public:
    CustomHTTPServer(ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory::Ptr pFactory,
                     Poco::UInt16 portNumber = 80,
                     Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::Ptr pParams = new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams)
      : Poco::Net::TCPServer(new CustomHTTPServerConnectionFactory(pParams, pFactory), portNumber, pParams) {}

    CustomHTTPServer(ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory::Ptr pFactory,
                     const Poco::Net::ServerSocket& socket,
                     Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::Ptr pParams = new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams)
      : Poco::Net::TCPServer(new CustomHTTPServerConnectionFactory(pParams, pFactory), socket, pParams) {}

    CustomHTTPServer(ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory::Ptr pFactory,
                     Poco::ThreadPool* threadPool,
                     const Poco::Net::ServerSocket& socket,
                     Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::Ptr pParams = new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams)
      : Poco::Net::TCPServer(new CustomHTTPServerConnectionFactory(pParams, pFactory), *threadPool, socket, pParams) {}
};
```

This class is simply forwarding the `pFactory, pParams` parameters to the `CustomHTTPServerConnectionFactory`, and initializes its base class `Poco::Net::TCPServer`.

**CustomHTTPServerConnectionFactory.hpp**

```
#pragma once
    
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerParams.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/TCPServerConnectionFactory.h"

#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp"
#include "CustomHTTPServerConnection.hpp"

class CustomHTTPServerConnectionFactory : public Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory {
 private:
    Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::Ptr pParams{};
    CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory::Ptr pFactory{};

 public:
    CustomHTTPServerConnectionFactory(Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::Ptr apParams,
                                      ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory::Ptr apFactory)
      : pParams{apParams}
      , pFactory{apFactory} {}

    Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection* createConnection(const Poco::Net::StreamSocket& socket) override {
        return new CustomHTTPServerConnection(socket, pParams, pFactory);
    }
};
```

This class provides a `Poco::Net::StreamSocket` through its base class `Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory`, which is forwarded along with `pParams, pFactory` to the `CustomHTTPServerConnection` constructor.

**CustomHTTPServerConnection.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerParams.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequestImpl.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponseImpl.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerSession.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/TCPServerConnection.h"

#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp"
#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"

class CustomHTTPServerConnection : public Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection {
 private:
    const Poco::Net::StreamSocket& socket{};
    Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::Ptr pParams{};
    ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory::Ptr pFactory{};

 public:
    explicit CustomHTTPServerConnection(const Poco::Net::StreamSocket& aSocket,
                                        Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::Ptr apParams,
                                        ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory::Ptr apFactory)
      : Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection(aSocket)
      , socket{aSocket}
      , pParams{apParams}
      , pFactory{apFactory} {}

    void run() override {
        Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession session(socket, pParams);
        Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponseImpl response(session);
        Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequestImpl request(response, session, pParams);
        ICustomHTTPRequestHandler::Ptr handler = pFactory->createRequestHandler(request);
        if (handler) {
            handler->handleRequest(session, request, response);
        }
    }
};
```

This is the class where the `session`, `response` and `request` variables are constructed, and passed to the appropriate handler. The handler is chosen by the request's path parameter in the user implemented `CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory`.

For example:

**CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/URI.h"
#include "Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h"

#include "HTTPRequestHandlerAdapter.hpp"
#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"
#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp"

#include "TimeHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"
#include "StreamHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"
#include "FaviconHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"
#include "PageHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"

class CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory : public ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory {    
 public:
    ICustomHTTPRequestHandler::Ptr createRequestHandler(const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request) override {
        const Poco::URI uri(request.getURI());
        const std::string path = uri.getPath();

        if (path == "/") {
            return new PageHTTPRequestHandler();
        } else if (path == "/time") {
            return new HTTPRequestHandlerAdapter(new TimeHTTPRequestHandler{});
        } else if (path == "/stream") {
            return new StreamHTTPRequestHandler();
        } else if (path == "/favicon.ico") {
            return new FaviconHTTPRequestHandler();
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

**FaviconHTTPRequestHandler.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerSession.h"

#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"
#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp"

class FaviconHTTPRequestHandler : public ICustomHTTPRequestHandler {
 public:
    void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession& session,
                       Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request,
                       Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) override {
        std::ignore = session;

        response.setVersion(request.getVersion());
        response.setStatus(Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse::HTTP_OK);
        response.setContentType("image/gif");
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        std::ostream& ostr = response.send();

        std::ifstream favicon("../assets/gomb_icon.gif");
        ostr << favicon.rdbuf() << std::flush;
    }
};
```

**PageHTTPRequestHandler.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerSession.h"

#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"
#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp"

class PageHTTPRequestHandler : public ICustomHTTPRequestHandler {
 public:
    void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession& session,
                       Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request,
                       Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) override {
        std::ignore = session;

        response.setVersion(request.getVersion());
        response.setStatus(Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse::HTTP_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        std::ostream& ostr = response.send();

        ostr << "<html><head><title>HTTPTimeServer powered by "
                "POCO C++ Libraries</title></head>"
                "<body><p style=\"text-align: center; "
                "font-size: 48px;\">Hello"
                "</p></body></html>"
             << std::flush;
    }
};
```

**StreamHTTPRequestHandler**

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerSession.h"
#include "Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h"

#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"
#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory.hpp"

class StreamHTTPRequestHandler : public ICustomHTTPRequestHandler {
 public:
    void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession& session,
                       Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request,
                       Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) override {
        std::string boundary = "--BOUNDARY--";
        response.setVersion(request.getVersion());
        response.setStatus(Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse::HTTP_OK);
        response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=" + boundary);
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.set("Connection", "Close");
        response.set("Cache-Control",
                     "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, false");
        response.set("Pragma", "no-cache");
        std::ostream& ostr = response.send();
        ostr << std::flush;

        std::ifstream favicon("../assets/gomb_icon.gif");
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << favicon.rdbuf();
        std::string buf = ss.str();

        while (true) {
            try {
                std::string prelude =
                    boundary + "\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: " + std::to_string(buf.length()) +
                    "\r\n\r\n";
                session.socket().sendBytes(prelude.c_str(), static_cast<int>(prelude.length()));
                session.socket().sendBytes(buf.c_str(), static_cast<int>(buf.length()));
            } catch (std::exception& e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**This class provides an example for detecting disconnected clients with Poco.**

### Adapter class

In case someone would also like to use the `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler` class along with `CustomHTTPRequestHandler` and the `CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory`, they will need the following adapter class:

**HTTPRequestHandlerAdapter.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"

#include "ICustomHTTPRequestHandler.hpp"

class HTTPRequestHandlerAdapter : public ICustomHTTPRequestHandler {
 private:
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler* adaptee;

 public:
    explicit HTTPRequestHandlerAdapter(Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler* anAdaptee)
      : adaptee(anAdaptee) {}

    ~HTTPRequestHandlerAdapter() {
        delete adaptee;
    }

    void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession& session,
                       Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request,
                       Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) override {
        std::ignore = session;
        adaptee->handleRequest(request, response);
    }
};
```

For example, if someone would like to use POCO C++ Server Page Compiler, the compiler will generate `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler` classes, something like the `TimeHTTPRequestHandler` class.

**TimeHTTPRequestHandler.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "Poco/Net/HTMLForm.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"

class TimeHTTPRequestHandler : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler {
 public:
    void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) override {
        response.setVersion(request.getVersion());
        response.setStatus(Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse::HTTP_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        Poco::Net::HTMLForm form(request, request.stream());
        std::ostream& responseStream = response.send();
        responseStream << "\n";

        Poco::DateTime now;
        std::string dt(Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(now, "%W, %e %b %y %H:%M:%S %Z"));
        responseStream << "\n";
        responseStream << "<html>\n";
        responseStream << "<head>\n";
        responseStream << "<title>HTTPTimeServer powered by POCO C++ Libraries and PageCompiler</title>\n";
        responseStream << "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1\">\n";
        responseStream << "</head>\n";
        responseStream << "<body>\n";
        responseStream << "<p style=\"text-align: center; font-size: 48px;\">";
        responseStream << (dt);
        responseStream << "</p>\n";
        responseStream << "</body>\n";
        responseStream << "</html>";
    }
};
```

The adapter makes it possible to use these classes with the `CustomHTTPRequestHandlerFactory`,
by returning a `new Net::HTTPRequestHandlerAdapter(new TimeHTTPRequestHandler{})`.

Comment: Looks like this subclass implementation which is actually used as the request class does give access to the socket https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/6b3aab0624955807e8fba168fb0423fbe449610b/Net/src/HTTPServerRequestImpl.cpp#L77
You just have to static_cast it like here: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/6b3aab0624955807e8fba168fb0423fbe449610b/NetSSL_Win/samples/HTTPSTimeServer/src/HTTPSTimeServer.cpp#L76

Answer (score 1):

Few options:

1. You can try "Poco::Net::Socket::select()", but it's OS limited.
2. Switch to a "Poco::Net::WebSocket" with ping/pong heartbeat. If a socket is closed, "receiveFrame()" will throw an exception.