# How to detect when stream has been closed in POCO HTTPRequestHandler?

Tags: c++, http, streaming, poco-libraries, multipart-mixed-replace

In my application I want to stream jpg images through a HTTP web server using the POCO library, and for this I am using `multipart/x-mixed-replace` content type in my response body. This means when a `GET` request arrives to the HTTP server, it is continously sending images to the client in parts in a single http response.

The stream should close and the request handler should return when the client closes the window. But my problem with the `HTTPServerResponse.send()` stream is that it only gets destroyed, when the response object is destroyed, so I do not know when the client has left, and when do I have to stop sending the images.

That is how the code looks like:

```
#pragma once    

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"
    
class StreamHandler : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler {
 public:
    void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) override {
        std::ifstream imgFile("../../assets/imgs/random.jpg");
        std::stringstream ss{};
        ss << imgFile.rdbuf();
        std::string buf = ss.str();

        std::string boundary = "--BOUNDARY--";
        response.setVersion(request.getVersion());
        response.setStatus(Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse::HTTP_OK);
        response.setChunkedTransferEncoding(false);
        response.setKeepAlive(false);
        response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=" + boundary);
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.set("Connection", "Close");
        response.set("Cache-Control",
                     "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, false");
        response.set("Pragma", "no-cache");
        std::ostream& ostr = response.send();

        while (true) { // <-- What is the stop condition?
            ostr << boundary << "\r\n";
            ostr << "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
                    "Content-Length: " +
                        std::to_string(buf.length()) + "\r\n\r\n";
            ostr << buf;
            ostr << "\r\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a way to detect whether the client has left?

PS: Possibly I would like a solution within the boundaries of `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler`. I do not want any solution that requires opening another port, or using another third party library only for the streaming. For example, I am already using [nadjieb/cpp-mjpeg-streamer](https://github.com/nadjieb/cpp-mjpeg-streamer) which is working great, but I want to simplify my code and depend only on POCO. In lower level libraries I saw good implementations that are using the following strategy:

```
while (true) {
    if (res) {
        res = http_res_send_chunk(req, part_buf, part_len);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

The send command returns with some positive integer in case of success, and with 0 if the send function failed. However, I cannot replicate this with POCO unfortunately. Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution and posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75427325/12664906). If my answer gets accepted, I will flag this question as a duplicate.